# Unity get Device rotation in 3D space

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, gyroscope

How do I get a devices current rotation along the 3 axis in real world space ?

`Input.gyro.attitute` should work theoretically, but ends up messing with the calibration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using `Input.acceleration` instead.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html

It gives you the data from each axis from 0 to 1 but using a Lerp to transform it to degrees should do the job.